# How do I perform a one to many map-reduce join?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

What about the one to many join case when we have:

**file1**

> personid1, name1
>
> personid2, name2

file2

> personid1, address2

file2

> personid2, address2

I want to have reducer output

> personid1, name1, address2
>
> personid2, name2, address2

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use personid as the key from your mappers.

Then you'll be sure to get all records belonging to one personid in one reducer as an iterator. Now you'll need to distinguish which record comes from which source, so its better to put an identifier onto the value.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class ExampleDriver extends Configured implements Tool {


  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = getConf();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration, this.getClass().getName());

    job.setJarByClass(ExampleDriver.class);

    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(PERSON_DIR), TextInputFormat.class, PersonMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(ADDRESS_DIR), TextInputFormat.class, AddressMapper.class);


    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(KeyWithPersonId.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setReducerClass(JoinPersonWithAddressReducer.class);

    LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class); // Not necessary. Can use simple FileOutputFormat.

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ExampleDriver(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I wanted to know how to specify the input files. There are many files like file 2 and 3 and all have to be joined to file1.

Comment: The mapreduce api has functions for adding multiple inputs... something called addInputs. Which you can call multiple times giving the path to your table and a mapper class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that each `personid` can have only one name but many addresses.

A mapper should scan all your input files and produce key-value pairs like this:

```
(personid1, (0, name1))
(personid2, (0, name2))
(personid1, (1, address2))
(personid2, (1, address2))
```

The integer flag `0` denotes that the record has come from the `file1` and the flag `1` denotes that the record has come from *other* type of file.

A reducer input will be:

```
(personid1, [(0, name1), (1, address2)])
(personid2, [(1, address2), (0, name2)])
```

The Hadoop can't guarantee the order of original values in the shuffle output, so I've changed this order in the second line above just to illustrate this. The reducer job is to decode the *value* of each record (the list in square brackets) - the pair `(flag, value)` with `flag = 0` will give you the name, and all the other pairs will give you all the addresses of this person.

Enjoy the Hadoop!